# Creating dynamcially multiple checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jquery function that generates/clones checkboxes in a dynamic way. I can add or delete as many checkboxes I want. I am having a little difficulty figuring doing two things: how to display `sub_item` checkbox when `main_item` checkbox is checked. Here is a [DEMO](http://holaweblearning.co.nf/test/dynamic_textbox.html)

Jquery

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedSection').length;
    var newNum = new Number(num + 1);

    var newSection = $('#pq_entry_' + num).clone().attr('id', 'pq_entry_' + newNum);
    newSection.find('input[type="text"]').val('');
    newSection.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
    newSection.children(':first').children(':first').attr('id', 'main_item_' + newNum).attr('name', 'main_item_' + newNum).attr('placeholder', 'Item #' + newNum + ' Name');
    newSection.children(':nth-child(2)').children(':first').attr('id', 'sub_item_' + newNum).attr('name', 'sub_item_' + newNum);
    newSection.children(':nth-child(3)').children(':first').attr('id', 'other_item_' + newNum).attr('name', 'other_item_' + newNum);
    newSection.insertAfter('#pq_entry_' + num).last();

    $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', '');

    if (newNum == 10) $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $('#btnDel').click(function () {
    var num = $('.clonedSection').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
    $('#pq_entry_' + num).remove(); // remove the last element

    // enable the "add" button
    $('#btnAdd').prop('disabled', '');

    // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
    if (num - 1 == 1) $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });

  $('#btnDel').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

HTML

```
      <div>
      <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">
        <input id="main_item_1" name="main_item_1" type="checkbox"><label>Main Item</label>
        </li>
          <li style="list-style-type: none;">
              <input id="sub_item_1" name="sub_item_1" type="checkbox"><label>Sub Item</label>
          </li>
         <li style="list-style-type: none;">
            <input id="other_item_1" name="other_item_1" type="checkbox"><label>Other Item</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <center><input type='button'  class="button tiny radius" id='btnAdd' value='Add Another' />
      <input type='button'   class="button tiny radius alert" id='btnDel' value='Delete Last' /></center>
      </div>
```

Display Result

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by this `how to displaying sub_item checkbox when main_item checkbox is checked.`

Comment: @FurquanKhan Sorry, I made it more clear. check my post again for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I did understand well, something like this:

```
$('#main-panel').on('click', '.main-item', function () {
    var $mainItem = $(this);
    var $subItem = $mainItem.parent().next('.sub-item');
    if ($mainItem.is(':checked')) {
        $subItem.show();
    } else {
        $subItem.hide();
    }
});
```

with this markup:

```
<div id="main-panel">
    <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="clonedSection">
        <li>
            <input id="main_item_1" class='main-item' name="main_item_1" type="checkbox" />
            <label>Main Item</label>
        </li>
        <ul class="sub-item" style='display: none;'>
            <li>
                <input id="sub_item_1" name="sub_item_1" type="checkbox" />
                <label>Sub Item</label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- same as yours -->
```

Live demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regisc/5634e/)

Comment: Is there a way when I click button `Add Another` to hide the next set of subitem checkboxes?

Comment: And also how can I do the following: if `main_item` is unchecked then uncheck the `sub_items`?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that your subitems are not really subitems at the moment. Put the subitems inside the item they are children of and then generate simple script. Like so

Html:

```
<div id="items">
    <ul id="pq_entry_1" class="mainitems">
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">
            <input id="main_item_1" name="main_item_1" type="checkbox" class="mainitem">
            <label>Main Item</label>
            <ul class="subitems">
                <li  style="list-style-type: none;">
                    <input id="sub_item_1" name="sub_item_1" type="checkbox" class="subitem">
                    <label>Sub Item</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li style="list-style-type: none;">
            <input id="other_item_1" name="other_item_1" type="checkbox" class="mainitem">
            <label>Other Item</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.subitems
{
    display: none;
}
```

Javascript (jQuery) the part you didn't yet have:

```
$(function () {
    $("#items").on("click", ".mainitem", function() { 
        $(this).closest("ul").find(".subitems")[$(this).prop("checked") ? "fadeIn": "fadeOut"]();
    });
});
```